# Unable to connect to firebird

Tags: ubuntu, firebird

I follow this [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5) almost line by line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search firebird2.5-*
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-superclassic
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-superclassic
```

At this stage I see a prompt that asks me to set a password for `SYSDBA`, so I set it to `root`. Then I do the rest:

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-examples firebird2.5-dev 
cd /usr/share/doc/firebird2.5-examples/examples/empbuild/
sudo gunzip employee.fdb.gz
sudo chown firebird.firebird employee.fdb
sudo mv employee.fdb /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/
```

And, finally:

```
$ isql-fb
SQL> connect "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb " user 'SYSDBA' password 'root';
```

As a result, I get these error messages:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
operating system directive open failed
-Permission denied
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: first guess: try `sudo isql-fb`

Comment: Hm. That is absolutely right. Now it works. Please, make an answer from this and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database file may be restricted to the superuser since you've been doing `sudo gunzip ..., sudo chown ..., sudo ...`

- try `sudo isql-fb` to work as a super user (not the best option)
- try `sudo chmod 777 employee.fdb` to make the file readable/writable by anyone (not the best option either)
- try `sudo useradd -G {user} firebird` to add yourself to the `firebird` group and `sudo chmod g+w employee.fdb` to make sure the employee.fdb has group-write permissions (recommended)

Comment: Another option is to make sure the Firebird server is started and connect through the server. If you don't specify the hostname, a local connection is made which needs sufficient user rights on the database, while connecting through the Firebird server will use the rights of the database server.

Comment: Fixing permissions with `chmod 777` is basically never correct. You need to figure out the correct permissions, but they are never 777.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I decided to post this solution:

You must do some things... first, let's see the security stuff...

In the file `/etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf`

`section: DatabaseAccess` it must be like this:

DatabaseAccess Restrict `/the/directory/you/want/to/put/the/database`

Now, in the file `/etc/firebird/2.5/aliases.conf` you put an alias and the directory...

`diryouwant = /the/directory/you/want/to/put/the/database/database.fdb`

Save and restart the firebird service like:

`sudo service firebird-2.5"theversionyouhave" restart`

You must change the directory owner like this:

`sudo chown firebird.firebird /the/directory/you/want/to/put/the/database`

And now you can use flamerobin without any trouble...