# How to configure firebird 3.0 or set rights so any user can create a DB

Tags: ubuntu, firebird, rights, firebird-3.0

I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird3.0) guide for firebird3.0 on ubuntu. It is outdated, since there is no more `employe.fdb` in the examples and you have to create it itself through the included sql script. My problem is, that I can only create this database if I use `isql-fb` as `sudo`. I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158878/unable-to-connect-to-firebird) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5) and I can connect without sudo now if I add `localhost:` to the path, but I still can't create a database. Like I don't even have a firebird goup to add myself to. If I try to create a database not as sudo I get this error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
operating system directive access failed
-Not a directory
```

Comment: Always connect through localhost, and use SYSDBA initially, and check the [language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-security) for information on how to create users and grant them privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed the steps on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird3.0 on Ubuntu 21.04 until `sudo apt-get install firebird3.0-examples firebird-dev`, and I skipped the step `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa/firebird3.0` as firebird3.0 is already in the default repository. Installation created a `firebird` group for me.

The essential step that is missing from that page is adding yourself to the group `firebird`. If you don't do this, you don't have access to some of the files and/or directories used by the Firebird Embedded engine (which is used when you don't specify a host name), which causes the error shown in your question.

Use `usermod -aG firebird <yourusername>` to add yourself, followed by `newgrp firebird` to refresh the group list in your current session*. You can then use `isql-fb` without specifying a host name like localhost. For example, using the instructions in `README.Debian` in `/usr/share/doc/firebird3.0-examples/examples/` to create the employee example database.

Keep in mind, when specifying only filenames in Firebird, you're using its Embedded mode, and files are accessed with the filesystem access rights of your current user. If you prefix it with `localhost:`, it will connect through the Firebird Server process on your machine using the filesystem access rights of the `firebird` user. This difference is important, because the `firebird` user has - for example - no access to your home directory.

To be able to create a database through Firebird Server, the user must have sufficient privileges to create databases. By default only the SYSDBA user has this privilege.

To be able to create users, you need to be attached to a database, with a user with sufficient privileges to creates users.

If you don't have a database yet, you can create one:

```sql
create database 'localhost:<path-to-db>' user sysdba password '<your password>';
```

If you already have a database, you can use:

```sql
connect 'localhost:<path-to-db>' user sysdba password '<your password>';
```

You can then create - as SYSDBA - additional users with [`CREATE USER`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-security-user-create):

```sql
CREATE USER NAMAL PASSWORD '12345';
```

To give this user the privilege to create a database, use - as SYSDBA - [`GRANT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-security-granting):

```sql
GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO USER NAMAL;
```

---

<sup>* Minor caveat: I didn't actually try `newgrp` myself, instead I rebooted my VM before I found this option</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you have Firebird Server run, you should not use embedded mode for databases creation or access. If you have Firebird Server stopped - remove its directories from /tmp before your attempts.

For precise diagnostic of the situation you can use strace to see exact parameters of the syscall mentioned in the error message.